# Is any a keyword in javascript, is it standard javascript syntax?

Tags: javascript

What is the "any" keyword in Javascript?

https://medium.com/code-well-live-forever/dry-up-your-api-requests-b4337049a2c1

Comment: Is it so hard to paste the same exact question you typed above into Google?

Comment: @Airwavezx You're right. Why do I need stack overflow at all.

Answer (score 1):

`any` in this context refers to Typescript’s any type.. this is not a javascript keyword